# Mysql INNER Join and Search Result With Exact Match

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data from multiple tables with a search keyword.

Here are my tables:

Table -1 translator

```
id | Name | English | User_id|

1  | کے  | ky       | 0      |
```

Table-2 boy

```
id | Name | English | meaning |

1  | علی | Ali  | بلند  |
```

Table-3 girls

```
id | Name | English | meaning|

1  | سحرش | Sahrish | جادو |
```

I want to get the English value with search keyword of `'علی'` from both tables.
How do I relate 3 tables with 2 columns where the column name is equal?
I want to get something like this:

```
id | Name | English |

1  | علی  | Ali     |
```

I'm trying this query:

```
 SELECT translator.Name,translator.English,boy.Name,boy.English,girls.Name,girls.English 
    FROM translator 
    INNER JOIN 
    (boy INNER JOIN girls 
    ON girls.Name = boy.Name) 
    ON translator.Name = boy.Name
    WHERE translator.Name = 'علی' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given query? If yes, please add a clear question

Comment: 0 result showing with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your result seems you need  a UNION (and not a JOIN)

```
select * from  (
    SELECT Name, English
    FROM translator 
    UNION 
    SELECT Name, English
    FROM boy
    UNION 
    SELECT Name, English
    FROM girls 

    ) t  
    where name  = 'yourvalue'
```